# Jersey test client does not consume JSON body

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I wrote a custom message body writer and reader for JSON with another library than the one packaged with Jersey. I am trying to test it out with a simple Java service and a test class. I got some problem though as the test client never gets to see the JSON body for reasons I cannot find. After enabling logging facilities, I see that the server seems to properly send the JSON data:

```
1:46:03 PM com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter$Adapter finish
INFO: 1 * Server out-bound response
1 < 200
1 < Content-Type: application/json
1 < 
{"id":1,"name":"Business Intelligence Team","parentTeam":{"id":2,"name":"Data Analysis Team"}}
```

But the client side never receives such body:

```
1:46:03 PM com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * Client in-bound response
1 < 200
1 < Content-Length: 0
1 < Date: Wed, 12 Feb 2014 18:46:03 GMT
1 < server: grizzly/2.2.16
1 < Content-Type: application/json
1 <
```

Debugging the Jersey libraries, I see that indeed, the `InputStream` is automatically set at a default `EmptyInputStream` object, as if this was never set properly, or does not acknowledge any input http body at least. Debugging my custom providers, they seem to work good and behaves correctly.

I am using Jersey version 1.18. This is my test class:

```
public class DeployResourceTest extends JerseyTest {
    private WebResource resource;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupJerseyLog() throws Exception {
        Handler fh = new ConsoleHandler(); // FileHandler("/tmp/jersey_test.log");
        Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(fh);
        Logger.getLogger("com.sun.jersey").setLevel(Level.FINEST);
    }

    public DeployResourceTest() {
        super(new WebAppDescriptor.Builder("com.deploymentnow.dnagent.services.rest")
                .contextParam("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:applicationContext.xml")
                .contextParam("log4jConfigLocation", "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/log4j.properties")
                .contextParam("webAppRootKey", "template-jersey-spring-jpa.root")
                .initParam("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.deploymentnow.agent.services.rest")
                .initParam("com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Trace", "true")
                .initParam("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames", "org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter")
                .initParam("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters", "com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter")
                .initParam("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters", "com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter")
                .clientConfig(new DefaultClientConfig(PlayJsonMessageBodyReader.class, PlayJsonMessageBodyWriter.class))
                .contextListenerClass(Log4jConfigListener.class)
                .contextListenerClass(ContextLoaderListener.class)
                .requestListenerClass(RequestContextListener.class)
                .servletClass(SpringServlet.class).build());
        this.resource = resource();
        resource.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
    }

    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
        return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
    }

    @Test
    public void testListResources() {
        ClientResponse response = resource.path("application/26/team").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(ClientResponse.class);
        Team team = response.getEntity(Team.class);
        Assert.assertNotNull(team);
    }

}
```

My web service, very minimal:

```
@Path("application/{application}")
public class DeployResource {

    @Path("team")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response testTeam() {
        Team team = new Team(1, "Business Intelligence Team", Option.<Team>apply(new Team(2, "Data Analysis Team", Option.<Team>empty())));
        return Response.status(200).entity(team).build();
    }

}
```

The message body writer. It implements a very specific type for the moment, as this is only meant for testing:

```
@Provider
@Produces("application/json")
public class PlayJsonMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Team> {
    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return type == Team.class && MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE.equals(mediaType);
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(Team o, Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        // deprecated by JAX-RS 2.0 and ignored by Jersey runtime
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Team team, Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        JsValue value = Json.toJson(team, DeploymentFormat.teamFormat());
        String str = value.toString();
        byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        entityStream.write(bytes);
    }
}
```

I am writing directly in the entity stream, as shown in the documentation and tutorials.. And the message body reader:

```
@Provider
@Consumes("application/json")
public class PlayJsonMessageBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader<Team> {

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return type == Team.class && MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE.equals(mediaType);
    }

    @Override
    public Team readFrom(Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        String body = IOUtils.toString(entityStream, "UTF-8");
        if (!hasText(body)) {
            return null;
        }
        JsValue json = Json.parse(body);
        JsResult<Team> result = Json.fromJson(json, DeploymentFormat.teamFormat());
        return result.get();
    }
}
```

I also tried to query the web service deployed in a Tomcat servlet container with a REST client and I had no response, despite the logging that seems to indicate otherwise. I was wondering if the logging somehow consumed the content body.. but even by disabling the logging, it did not work.

---

UPDATE

I was able to make my things work, but not by directly fixing my issue, but rather by switching the JAX-RS implementation from **Jersey** to **Apache CXF**. There is no difference in code; it just works.

The main difference that I see is the output stream type used. In my provider, Jersey sends me some `CommittingOutputStream` parameter that seems to have more abstraction and a bit sensitive. For example, I've noticed that invoking the `flush` method on it makes the stream's content go away completely, with no chance to even appear in the logging.

In the case of Apache CXF, the output stream type is `CachedOutputStream`. It behaves as expected and the content is actually sent out to the client.

I haven't found why it does not work in **Jersey**. It was quicker to just dump it and get something that does the job, a.k.a. **Apache CXF**.

I'll leave the issue opened, in case that someone from the Jersey team can answer for this erratic behavior.

Comment: Strange, why does the inbound Content-Length = 0 in the second snippet?

Comment: @mikemil I have no idea why, as it seems some content was sent at least from the server. I'll put the custom providers that I've wrote too!